# Is the hard coded value in function argument a const reference?

Tags: c++

Why does the following program fail to compile:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int fun(int &x)
{
    return x;
}
int main()
{
    cout << fun(10);
    return 0;
}
```

It gives the following compilation error:
invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'int&' from an rvalue of type 'int'

To make it compile successfully , I have 2 options:
1. we have to use "int fun(const int &x)" instead of "int fun(int &x)"
2. use "int i=10;cout << fun(i);" instead of "cout << func (10)"

So, it seems like , if we pass a hard coded value to a function , it will be treated like "const reference".

Am I right here? or is there any other reason that above program doesn't compile?

Comment: You can simply remove '&' and use pass-by-value instead of pass-by-reference.

Comment: yes , that will work of-course , but Q was why it don't work with &.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This doesn't compile because non-const lvalue references cannot bind to rvalues.

Think about it this way: if `x` in `fun` is a non-const lvalue reference, we should be able to modify it. However, we have passed in the integer literal `10`. What should it mean to modify an integer literal? That doesn't make sense, so you can't.

To fix this, you should take your argument in by reference-to-const (assuming you don't plan on modifying it in `fun`):

```
int fun(const int &x)
```

Comment: thanks , it gives a clear understanding, so it mean "10" and "&x" is exactly same , I thought , "x is a reference to 10 ", so there is a difference in a reference to  CONSTANT , and reference to variable which contain constant :)